# Parent folder visibility with limited access permissions in sharepoint online

Tags: document-library, permissions, folder, inheritance

Inside a site collection, i have a subsite, and a document library within that.  On the document library i have broken inheritance.  In the library i have folders 1 or more deep.  On a 2nd, 3rd or more deeper folder level i share to user.  Eg i am using folder/item level permissions.

Sharepoint automatically gives the user limited permissions to reach the specific folder, however only with a direct link.  The user cannot browse the subsite, or the document library, which makes sense because they don't have read permission on the parent objects.

I cannot convince my client to use meta data and forget folders, or even custom lists, so for now i am "stuck" with the old school familiar folder hierarchy.

I don't want to enable the 1990's "tree view", and a "flat folder" view does not work because of the file naming, it makes no sense when files are not in folders...  Yes, i know... you feel me?

So, what other options are there to display a "breadcrumbs" or folder path, or surface some links at the parent levels, or some fancy javascript code to surface something to allow the user to browse the document library and click through to their files?

Calling all sharepoint coders!

Comment: Great question @ajhstn, did you ever find a workable solution to this situation? I've a similar business case now. Microsoft now recommends to migration on premise files structure to SharePoint Online but without similar NTFS folder permissions of listing folders, I'm not sure how we can convivence the end users to move to the Microsoft Cloud.

With SPO limited access permissions, users get access to the parent folder only to view but not any higher level. Like you said it's not workable for end-users to come to the library always with a direct link. 

Hope to hear from others.